# Verbal form in the famous aria "Nessun dorma"

Tags: grammar, verbs

The verbal form of 'dorma' in the aria *Nessun dorma* from Puccini's *Turandot* recently struck me as strange given that there is nothing to trigger a subjunctive preceding the verb.

My question is first what form of dormire is being used: formal imperative, present subjunctive or some other form?

Second, how should this line best be understood given the form?

Comment: This absolute use of subjunctive mood in Italian, not “triggered” by another proposition, is known as [*congiuntivo esortativo*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/congiuntivo-esortativo_(La-grammatica-italiana)/).

Answer (score 4):

It's the subjunctive used for denoting [desire or will](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congiuntivo#Desiderio.2C_volont.C3.A0):

> (I want that) nobody be sleeping (tonight)

or

> Nobody should be sleeping

The imperative properly has only the second person (singular and plural); in the other persons it's substituted with the corresponding forms of the present subjunctive. So you can consider it as the imperative as well.